# TCP socket communication from client to server

Tags: networking, tcp, sockets

I am trying to test the performance of a client/server application that uses TCP communication.

If I trigger multiple requests from the client, would it flow through the same connection/pipe to the server or would it open separate connections for each request?

I'm trying to understand if we need multiple machines to emulate real-time testing or if each request from the client will open a separate connection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either. You'll have to run a sniffer and see what it does.

Even if it uses HTTP (which is TCP-based) it could use HTTP persistent connections (i.e. the "Connection: Keep-Alive" header stuff) to do multiple requests over one TCP session, or it could do one TCP connection for each HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks.So does it depend on the setting on the load balancer. We are testing the below scenario, where the client send a TCP request to the load balancer. Would it be the configuration on the LB to force multiple request over one TCP session?